# Почему происходит перенос текста в div с with:auto при наличии места ?

Tags: html, css

Происходит перенос пункта меню "Программы", хотя width для #menu не задано, места для контента навалом. Почему происходит перенос? И как можно этого избежать?

css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI'
}

header {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff
}

header #logo {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 4px 1.8315018% 14px 8.42490842490842%
}

header #logo p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 47px;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle
}

header #logo p .red {
    color: #f03
}

header #menu {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: auto
}

header #menu p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 23px;
    border-bottom: 1px #fff dashed;
    margin-right: 4.37062937062937%;
}

header #menu p a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none
}

header #user-block {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 18.82783882783883%;
    right: 0
}

header #user-block p {
    display: inline-block
}
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>fizzy.kg</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="less/main.less">

</head>
<body>

<header>
    <div id=logo>
        <p><img src="images/logo.png"></p>
        <p><span class="red">fi</span>zzy<span class="red">.kg</span></p>
    </div>
    <div id=menu>
        <p><a href="">Фильмы</a></p>
        <p><a href="">Сериалы</a></p>
        <p><a href="">Мультсериалы</a></p>
        <p><a href="">Программы</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="user-block">
        <p><img src="/images/success.png"></p>
        <p>Nafigator</p>
    </div>
</header>

<script src="js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/less/less.js"></script>
<script src="js/gridpak/gridpak.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Что это такое?

```
margin-right: 4.37062937062937%;
```

4.37062937062937 процента от чего? Ширина авто стоит.

Инлайн блоки не занимают всю доступную ширину.

Если задать точное значение margin-right для menu p это будет решение .

Меню - nav ul li.

p - абзац.

Answer (score -1):

1. при верстке не используй id. В принципе, их можно использовать, но это плохая практика. Они предназначены в основном для доступа к элементу через JS. Юзай классы.
2. inline-block убери со всех дивов и учись использовать float. И тогде увидишь как все элементы красиво стают на свои места

Comment: я с первым пунктом не согласен, если элемент единственный, то он должен быть именно id.

Comment: @eicto, создавая id, вы неявно создаете переменную js c таким же именем. а если таких id много, зачем этот мусор?

Comment: А я бы еще и по поводу второго пункта поспорил. Просто надо уметь использовать **inline-block** и учитывать особенности его поведения.

Comment: извините ребята, что я всем даю неправильные советы. я же тупой начинающий верстальщик

Comment: а id не должно быть много :) именно в этом смысл рекомендации не использовать id . вот то что в header не надо id определять. тем более что тут html5 это верно.

Comment: тут как раз первый пункт верный, а второй - это очень плохая практика. Много флоатов - вон из верстки:) Такое пишут везде где пишут о верстке, флоат - там где картинка, обтекаемая текстом например, а для блоков разных это плохо, инлайн блок намного лучше.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, float и inline-block нужно использовать в разных контекстах верстки. я не говорил что абсолютно везде нужны флоаты

Comment: ну, у него флоат, то не нужно вот для меню, а инлайн блок будет нормально. А айди при верстке не используются, да. Хотя я видел на многих cайтах - http://apple.com , например. Так что тут тоже все как-то мутно.

Comment: да блин, сколько вам можно повторять, надо не избегать использования ID а избегать таких  случаев когда вам необходимо использовать id, вы перепутали причину и следствие и радостно справляете карго-культ.

Comment: А когда необходимо использовать? Разве что когда  нужно обращаться с javascript, нет?

Comment: `class="mySingleUsedElement"` это идиотизм. так понятнее ? тут надо использовать id, другое дело, что элементов `mySingleUsedElement` в идеальной верстке вообще не должно быть.

---

я это всё читал, моя позиция выражена семантике id и class. Скажем "Петр Иванов" это id, а классы у него "мужик, гражданин РФ" и заводить на него класс "Петр Иванов" никто не станет.

Comment: Чтобы юзать `inline-block` надо размер щрифта в обертке сделать нулевым, а в самих блоках вернуть его обратно, путем явного задания, тогда не будет этих непонятных отступов между блоками.

Comment: Почему идиотизм, допустим потом надо внутри еще добавить что-то,. Писать вот так #mySingleUsedElement .inner даже медленее , чем с классом.

Save IDs for fragment identifiers or JavaScript hooks.
http://screwlewse.com/2010/07/dont-use-id-selectors-in-css/

Так все пишут про идентификаторы, для верстки и css - классы используются. Читал об этом много раз. Идиотизма никакого нет. 

С другой стороны на практике айдишки очень часто используются и для верстки, как кто хочет, в общем, я не использую.